# Getting undefined value while connecting SQL Server to nodejs with mssql package

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, express

I am getting the error below while connecting to SQL Server from node.js using mssql package.

```
PS F:\Visual Studio Code\NodeSQLServer> node dboperations.js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'port')
    at new ConnectionPool (F:\Visual Studio Code\NodeSQLServer\node_modules\mssql\lib\base\connection-pool.js:60:36)
    at new ConnectionPool (F:\Visual Studio Code\NodeSQLServer\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:10:1)
    at Object.connect (F:\Visual Studio Code\NodeSQLServer\node_modules\mssql\lib\global-connection.js:18:24)
    at getResult (F:\Visual Studio Code\NodeSQLServer\dboperations.js:6:36)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Visual Studio Code\NodeSQLServer\dboperations.js:16:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
undefined
```

I have created two js files to fetch required data from SQL Server.

First file is dbconfig.js. Code of the file is below:

```
const config = {
    user : 'Tableau',
    password : 'tableau@2023',
    server : 'DESKTOP-I933IRB',
    database : 'Rane',
    port : 1433,
    options : {
        trustedConnection : true,
        enableArithAbort : true,
        instancename : 'SQLEXPRESS',
        encrypt : true,
        trustServerCertificate : true
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

second file is dboperations.js with the code below:

```
let { config } = require('./dbconfig');
const sqlServer = require('mssql');

const getResult = async ()=>{
    try{
        let pool = await sqlServer.connect(config);
        let result = await pool.request().query('Select top 5 * From config_table_master');
        //console.log(result.recordsets);
        return result.recordsets;        
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(e);
    }
}

getResult().then(result => {
    console.log(result);
})
```

Besides, the query is running fine on SSMS.

[image: Result of the query used in node]

Please, let me know why the error occurred and how can I avoid such errors in the future.

Comment: Why do you specify the port and the instance name in your connection? If you're passing the instance name then the browser service will "point" the connection to the correct port. Generally, as well, Express doesn't run on port 1433; have you changed your instance to run on the default port? If not then specifing port 1433 is likely pointing to the wrong instance (or even one that doesn't exist).

Comment: I am a beginner in node.js. I am very sorry if I made a blunder in the file. I was trying to create a backend connection by watching online tutorials and ended up here. Is there a way to resolve this error??

Comment: I think you've missed my point. You specify both the port and instance name in your connection details, but both aren't needed. Which is it you should be passing, the port or the instance name? Your image of SSMS doesn't appear to show a instance name either, so do you actually not need either?

Comment: I have tried all the combinations you explained. First, I have commented out either port or instance name. Later, I commented out both. But still, I am getting undefined value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your import statement since you are doing a default export:

```
let config = require('./dbconfig');
```

For more info check [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-module-exports-explained-with-javascript-export-function-examples/) out.

Comment: It worked. Thank you @lpizzinidev for the help. Now I can proceed further in my journey of learning the backend. Thank you again.